# How to get longitude latitude of multiple addresses geo-location

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation

I am using geo location api http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ADDRESS&sensor=false

But the problem is I have above 500-1000 results who's long/lat I need. What I loop through geolocation api it nearly stuck the page.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/curl_multi_exec) is a good option. And keep in mind you can only make 2,500 geocoding requests in a day.

Comment: My requirements are move then 2500, is there any way i can do more then 2500 requests per day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to geocode ahead of time and store the results in a local database.  It is not appropriate to geocode so many points on the fly when a page loads for the user.

Also, pay attention to drew010's comment about the max number of requests in a day.

Comment: My requirements are move then 2500, is there any way i can do more then 2500 requests per day?

Comment: Yes, you can do 100,000 per day if you are a [Google Maps API For Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) user.  Source: https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: I get this API link from one of my friend http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#street2coordinates is it worth using? I can pass an array of locations to this.